# How to fix precision in Symja?

Tags: java, precision, symja

I'm using [Symja](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library).

On http://matheclipse.org/, when I run the following formula:

```
round(100*17347*0.047)*0.01
```

I get: `815.31`

When running the following Java code

```
ExprEvaluator exprEvaluator = new ExprEvaluator(false,100);
double d = exprEvaluator.evalf("round(100*17347*0.047)*0.01");
System.out.println(d);
```

I get: `815.3100000000001`

What am I missing ?

Comment: `System.out.println(exprEvaluator.evalf("round(100*17347*0.047)*0.01"));` gives result highly likely `815.3100000000001`, the result has nothing to with it being `double` or the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wrong with the code. If you wish to get only 2 precision of the number, I mean to print, use `printf()` in lieu of `println()`

```
ExprEvaluator exprEvaluator = new ExprEvaluator(false,100);
double d = exprEvaluator.evalf("round(100*17347*0.047)*0.01");
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", d);
```

Or, if you want its numerical rounded value, you can use Java's `DecimalFormat`

```
double d = 815.3100000000001;
System.out.println(d);

DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double twoDecimal =  Double.valueOf(newFormat.format(d));
System.out.println(twoDecimal);
```

Even more, if you are uncomfortable with its behaviour, override the `evalf` method and use `Math.round(...)` within it. It results in your wish without needing additional Java methods. Moreover, you should glance at implementation of `evalf`.